# remove extra spaces in string in javascript

Tags: javascript, string, whitespace

I have a text and after deleting special characters (!@#$%^&*()-=+`";:'><.?/) and show just letters and numbers (and float numbers like 23.4 ) it returns some extra space

```
    const input : 'this is a signal , entry : 24.30 and side is short';

    const text = input.replace(/\.(?!\d)|[^\w.]/g, " ").toUpperCase();

    console.log(text.split(" "))
```

the output :

```
[
  'THIS',   'IS',    'A',
  'SIGNAL', '',      '',
  '',       'ENTRY', '',
  '',       '24.30', 'AND',
  'SIDE',   'IS',    'SHORT'
]
```

but I want to be this :

```
[
  'THIS',   'IS',    'A',
  'SIGNAL', 'ENTRY', '24.30',  
  'AND',    'SIDE',   'IS',     
  'SHORT'
]
```

And when I replace spaces and enters with empty string , returns this  :

```
[ 'THISISASIGNALENTRY24.30ANDSIDEISSHORT' ]
```

what is the problem of my code?

Comment: Your current code produces a SyntaxError.

Comment: Why don't you just replace with an empty string if you don't want the spaces?

Comment: plop a `.filter(Boolean)` on it

Comment: @RaniSharim edited , check it again please

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Instead of replacing, consider *matching* all the sorts of characters you want to produce the array of words. It looks like you want something like:

```js
const input = 'this is a signal , entry : 24.30 and side is short';
const matches = input.toUpperCase().match(/[\w.]+/g);
console.log(matches);
```

Comment: `_` are word characters. If you want to exclude them, replace `\w` with all the characters you want to match, eg `/[a-z0-9.]+/gi`

Comment: But I want the dots not to be at the output , just only for float numbers like 34.2. with this regex when I have a dot in the text, it returns it.

Comment: Alternate word-ish characters (without dots) with numbers with dots then. `/[a-z]+|\d+(?:\.\d+)?/gi`

Answer (score 0):

The second parameter in the `replace` method needs to be an empty string and not a space as you have it in your code.

Just do:

```
...
const text = input.replace(/\.(?!\d)|[^\w.]/g, "").toUpperCase();
...
```

Comment: when I use a empty string , return this : `[ 'THISISASIGNALENTRY24.30ANDSIDEISSHORT' ]`